# Is there a way to move an object file to file?

Tags: objects, blend-files

I've made a human head and a body in blender but I don't know how to combine this 2 separated objects to 1 blender file.

Any solutions?

Comment: see https://www.blender.org/manual/data_system/linked_libraries.html, it is possible and easy, you can use File > Append

Answer (score 0, accepted):

two ways i know,

1. file> append on one of the blend files, I don't find this as good.
2. have both files open and copy one object Ctrl-C and paste it Ctrl-V in the other blend file.

Hope this helps.